(gvt-apex): New API SSL cert issue in Apexcloud. http 526 error was returned
We’ve applied certificate and tested but I got the below error.

/O error on POST request for https://gw-stg.int.api.gov.sg/sps/prisap/postman/api/v2/campaigns/campaign_b60cf8a0-dc41-4822-867c-1203147c8319/messages: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certify

http 526 was returned. How do we refresh the certificate in Apexcloud?
After renewing our certificate, we got hit with http 526. We are expecting the API to work as expected. i.e. return http 200.

Please check your formatting, so people will be more motivated to dive into your issue.
